# Stopping Powershell script execution on error in SharePoint 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint Powershell Script in .ps1 format and it includes 4 commands.
When I run this script, it does not stop if any error occurs in middle.

For example, if error occurs at 2nd command it displays error message and starts executing the 3rd command, but I want it to stop at 2nd command and it should not execute any following commands.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl + X to cancel the script execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify -erroraction parameter value to stop. If you want same behavior for all commands in your script, set $ erroractionpreference value to stop before executing any commands.

Comment: i tried as below but same issue: the 1st command is : New-SPWebApplication -Name $name -ApplicationPool $applicationpool -ApplicationPoolAccount $applicationpoolaccount -Port $port -AuthenticationProvider $both -HostHeader $hostHeader -AllowAnonymousAccess -erroraction stop     and the 2nd command is :New-SPSite -Url $URL -OwnerAlias $creden -Template $template -erroraction stop            when there is error in firsty command it should not execute 2nd one.

Comment: still waiting for solutions.....

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using try/catch blocks. An example on how to use this is in the first answer at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456863/powershell-try-catch-rethrow-not-propagating-error-powershell-2-0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ErrorAction Parameter to stop. To see which values are valid for the ErrorAction parameter you should use

```
Get-Help about_commonparameters
```

try-catch-finally is used as in many other programming languages

```
try
{
   DoSomethingThatMayFail;
}
catch
{
   LogError;
}
finally
{
   Cleanup;
}
```